# Рекурсивная выборка из MariaDB всех связей

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Мой запрос выполняет бесконечный рекурсивный поиск, я понимаю проблему но не вижу решения.

Моя таблица:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `a` (`a`,`b`,`x`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`a`, `b`, `x`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 5),
(3, 2, 2),
(3, 2, 4),
(3, 3, 2),
(4, 3, 2),
(4, 3, 3),
(5, 3, 4),
(6, 3, 4);
```

Моя задача получить все связи строк используя то поле `X` то поля `A и B`.

Сначала находим все записи с условием `a = 4   b = 3` затем ищем все записи совпадающие с `X` и у найденных записей ищем уже с новыми условиями и так рекурсивно.

Я использовал следующий запрос, но получаю бесконечную рекурсию и понимаю почему так происходит, но не понимаю что необходимо добавить дабы остановить бесконечную рекурсию. Я пробовал использовать LIMIT но это не даёт никакого эффекта, полагаю я копаю не в ту сторону.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte (a, b, x) as (
    SELECT      a, b, x
    FROM        mytable
    WHERE       a = 4 AND b = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      m.a, m.b, m.x
    FROM        mytable m
    INNER JOIN  cte ON m.x = cte.x
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

[image: Небольшой визуальный фрагмент связей]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для исключения бесконечной рекурсии следует использовать UNION DISTINCT.

Поскольку требуется на нечётном шаге связывать по `x`, а на чётном по `(a, b)` - используются два рекурсивных блока.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT a, b, x FROM test WHERE (a, b) = (4, 3)
  UNION 
  SELECT test.a, test.b, x FROM test JOIN cte USING (x)  
  UNION 
  SELECT a, b, test.x FROM test JOIN cte USING (a, b)
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY a, b, x
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bi2IxyrO)

PS. Есть такая шутка: "Чтобы понять, как выполняется рекурсия, надо понять, как выполняется рекурсия". Однако в данном случае и в приведённой формулировке это не шутка, а чёткая и совершенно однозначная инструкция.

Comment: Да, это работает с описанной задачей. Я применил этот запрос у себя и получил необходимый результат. Однако, когда я пытаюсь применить данный запрос в таблице где есть тысячи других связей, в том числе `a = 0 и b = 0` как я могу исключить выборку этих записей? Я уже сделал `WHERE a <> 0 and b <> 0` на четном шаге, однако это не дало никакого эффекта.

Comment: Это я к тому, что записи со значениями `a = 0 и b = 0` имеют другие значения `x` которые в свою очередь имеют другие связи `a и b` что приводит к выборке тысяч записей, даже которые изначально не ожидалось получить. Т.е всё что мне нужно это исключить все нулевые значения.

Comment: *Я уже сделал WHERE a <> 0 and b <> 0 на четном шаге, однако это не дало никакого эффекта.* Условие надо вводить на первом шаге - `SELECT test.a, test.b, x FROM test JOIN cte USING (x) WHERE (a, b) <> (0, 0)`. На втором шаге эти значения просто не будут присутствовать в условии связывания. PS. Пока что Вы не поняли, как выполняется рекурсия - это плохо.

Comment: За долгое время работы с бд у меня данная задача появилась впервые, более того я впервые столкнулся с таким как USING и WITH RECURSIVE. Все мы научились водить только через практику. Кажется, вы помогли мне решить главную задачу, рекурсивно благодарен!

Comment: @МистерЛис Рекурсия выполняется до тех пор, пока на очередной итерации все блоки не отработают "вхолостую", не добавив записей в итоговый набор.